# two emails same domain

Tags: email, postfix

I'm confused about how to change my postfix settings to simply add 2 emails based on 1 domain. According to the manual it should be something like this:

```
 /etc/postfix/main.cf:
     virtual_alias_domains = example.com (...other hosted domains here if needed...)
     virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

 /etc/postfix/virtual:
     postmaster@example.com postmaster
     info@example.com       joe
     sales@example.com      jane
     (...virtual aliases for more domains...)
```

my current working postfix settings here (this works for info@g3eo.com):

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:

    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
    biff = no
    append_dot_mydomain = no
    readme_directory = no
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    recipient_delimiter = +
    inet_interfaces = loopback-only
    inet_protocols = all
    smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
    smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    smtpd_use_tls=yes
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
    smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks
    myhostname = pcelgery
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
    mydestination = pcelgery, localhost.com, localhost
    relayhost = smtp.zoho.com:587
    smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/password
    smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
    smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
    smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,defer_unauth_destination

/etc/postfix/generic:
    root info@g3eo.com

/etc/postfix/password:
    smtp.zoho.com:587 info@g3eo.com:DonaldMcDonaldKangreBurger

/etc/postfix/smtp_header_checks:
    /^From:.*/ REPLACE From:info@g3eo.com

/etc/postfix/tls_policy:
    smtp.zoho.com:587 encrypt
```

Based on the above configuration, I need to add another email (info@ceinia.org) that also goes through smtp.zoho.com:587.

So, how can adapt my above configuration to do so? do I need virtual_maps and aliases in postfix main.cf to achieve this?

Any pointers are much appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already configured postfix for your domain, let's say *@example.com*. 
That means postfix must deliver email to every user defined in your host *pcelgery*. Example: *root@example.com*

So, answering your questions

> How to add new mailboxes to your domain?

Just create a new O.S. user.

> Do you need virtual_maps and aliases?

No, unless you want to deliver email to other local or remote domains.

Hope that clarifies the issue